# Entity Framework | Add entity to DB with other entity in it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have these entities

```
[Table("Entity")]
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Products Product { get; set; }
} 

[Table("Products")]
public class Products
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

When I add a new entity to the database with this code:

```
 _context.Entities.Add(someentity);
 _context.SaveChanges();
```

**Products product** also try to add to database. But I don't want it because this entity already exists.

I tried to use `AsNoTracking`.

```
var product = _context.Product.AsNoTracking().Where(x=>x.ProductId == Id).FirstOrDefault();

var entity = new Entity{Id = 1, Product = product};
_context.Entity.Add(entity );
_context.SaveChanges();
```

and add virtual

```
 public virtual Products Product { get; set; }
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Adding `AsNoTracking()` would make it worse. EF must know that it is an already existing entity.

Comment: Does your `Entity` class has a property for the foreign key of the `Products` entity?

Comment: I could add the public int ProductId property to your entity class.. I am not sure how .net is handling that implicit relation between product and entity..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which generates the exception when executed.

Comment: Progman foreign key exist.   Rolando  I can public int ProductId but then i cant use Include()

Comment: After removing the `AsNoTracking()` method, the code works well on my side. You could try to remove it when query the exist Product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with this a lot in the past. At the time and as far as I know, there's not a way to say to EF, "this nested object may or may not be in the table. If it's primary key is already there, don't try to insert it again".

The workaround was to do this:

```
someentity.Product = _context.Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == someEntity.Product.Id) ?? someentity.Product;
_context.Entities.Add(someentity);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

If you set the value from the database then it knows it's the exact same object and will not try to add it in.